# Error al iniciar app de react: 0308010C digital envelope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

espero que puedan ayudarme. Cuando trato de iniciar una app de react me salta este error. Alguien puede entender por que ocurre esto?

Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.18363.1556]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

C:\Users\Gere>cd desktop

C:\Users\Gere\Desktop>cd my-app

C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app>npm start

> my-app@0.1.0 start

> react-scripts start

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.1.61/

i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from

i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app\public

i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /

Starting the development server...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

```
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
at module.exports (C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at handleParseError (C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
at C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
at C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
at C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
```

C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
throw err;
^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

```
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
at module.exports (C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
at C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
at C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
at context.callback (C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
at C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {
```

opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],

library: 'digital envelope routines',

reason: 'unsupported',

code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.2.0

C:\Users\Gere\Desktop\my-app>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta cambiar en tu package.json la siguiente línea:

```
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

por

```
"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, con eso se resolvió

Comment: me alegro, a las órdenes!